# Sniff my own Packets (non-Administrator)

Tags: windows, non-admin, sniffing

Running in Windows (Windows 7), I'm trying to sniff my browser's requests.

I can install tools that sniff packets for all users, and require high permissions.

But, I would like to just run a tool to sniff my own packets and not require those permissions. Does such a tool or method exist? Ideally, I would like an extension for my browser to intercept all requests (and plugin requests, too).

If not, then what level of (Windows) permission do I need or which policy do I need to set to give the account permission to sniff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are required to have Administrator priveledges to install any software. Therefore, I believe the work-around for you is simply to only use "portable" applications. "Portable" applications are ones where you simply unzip and use it, no installation required.

Check out:

- [Portable Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/WiresharkPortable) (gets rave reviews)
- [Smart Sniff](http://www.pendriveapps.com/smartsniff-network-packet-sniffer/)

Comment: No problems installing software. I was just having problems running certain sniffers.

Comment: I would love to sniff all local programms running and calling home EXCEPT my browser (so basically, apart from very few legitimate updates, anyone without my 'consent')...